# pdfbox - sign landscape file error

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using **pdfbox-1.8.8** to do the signing function on PDF file.

It works well with PDF file in portrait mode. But with landscape file, I have an issue

[image: Position of signatory I want to sign]

[image: Result of the sign]

It looks like the coordinate is wrong for the landscape file.

Does anyone know what is wrong with the file ?

Here is the link of [pdf file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwLd99D2Ui9VQnFoV0c4b3Yyd2c/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the code I used to sign

```
public void signDetached(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath, String signatureImagePath, Sign signProperties) {
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    PDDocument document = null;
    InputStream signImageStream = null;

    try {
        setTsaClient(null);
        document = PDDocument.load(inputFilePath);
        // create signature dictionary
        PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
        signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
        signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        signature.setName("VANDUC1102");
        signature.setLocation(null);
        String displayName = "Hello World, Document signed by VANDUC1102";
        String reason = reasonText+ " " + displayName;
        signature.setReason(reason);

        // the signing date, needed for valid signature
        signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());            
        int signatureInPage = signProperties.getPageNumber() + 1;
        signImageStream = new FileInputStream(new File(signatureImagePath));
        PDVisibleSignDesigner visibleSig = new PDVisibleSignDesigner(inputFilePath, signImageStream, signatureInPage);

        float xAxis = convertPixel2Point(signProperties.getX()) ;
        float yAxis = convertPixel2Point(signProperties.getY());               
        float signImageHeight = convertPixel2Point(signImageHeight);    
        float signImageWidth = convertPixel2Point(signImageWidth);

        visibleSig.xAxis(xAxis)
                .yAxis(yAxis)
                .zoom(0)
                .signatureFieldName("Signature")
                .height(signImageHeight)
                .width(signImageWidth);
        PDVisibleSigProperties signatureProperties = new PDVisibleSigProperties();

        signatureProperties.signerName(eiUser.getName())
                 .signerLocation(null)
                 .signatureReason(reason)
                 .preferredSize(0)
                 .page(signProperties.getPageNumber())
                 .visualSignEnabled(true)
                 .setPdVisibleSignature(visibleSig)
                 .buildSignature();
         // register signature dictionary and sign interface
        SignatureOptions signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();
        signatureOptions.setVisualSignature(signatureProperties);
        signatureOptions.setPage(signatureInPage);
        document.addSignature(signature, this, signatureOptions);

        File outputFile = new File(outputFilePath);
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFilePath);
        IOUtils.copyStream(inputStream, outputStream);
        document.saveIncremental(inputStream, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (COSVisitorException | SignatureException | IOException ex) {
        log.error("signDetached ", ex);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeStream(outputStream);
        IOUtils.closeStream(inputStream);
        IOUtils.closeStream(signImageStream);
        IOUtils.closeStream(document);
    }
}
private float convertPixel2Point(float pixel){
    return pixel * (float) 72/96;
}
```

As I said this code work well with portrait PDF

Thanks.

Comment: Most likely the page has a portrait- oriented coordinate system and is landscape only because it also has a **Rotate** value telling PDF viewers to rotate it for display.

Comment: Indeed each page dictionary contains a `/Rotate 90` entry (lines 484-519 if opened as text)

Comment: Thus, the OP has to take the rotation into account when applying the signature. As he hasn't shown any code yet, not even explained whether the "signature" is a mere image or actually a filled AcroForm signature field, it is highly speculative to say anything more.

Comment: Ah, according to the code the OP meanwhile has added to his question, he indeed tries to add an integrated PDF signature there. Unfortunately the PDFBox classes for creating visible such signatures are horrible. As far as I can see they ignore the page rotation. Thus, either you extend those classes to explicitly support rotated pages or you read the page rotation yourself, re-calculate the position and sizes of your signature, rotate your image, and use the PDFBox classes using these revised data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page in question has a non-zero **Rotate** value. The PDFBox visual signing classes completely ignore this value, so one has to give it the coordinates and dimensions as if the page was not rotated.

This can be done by adding the following `switch` statement:

```
float xAxis = convertPixel2Point(/*signProperties.getX()*/x) ;
float yAxis = convertPixel2Point(/*signProperties.getY()*/y);               
float signImageHeight = convertPixel2Point(/*signImageHeight*/324);    
float signImageWidth = convertPixel2Point(/*signImageWidth*/309);

int rotation = getPageRotation(inputFilePath, page) % 360;
switch (rotation)
{
case 0:
    // all ok;
    break;
case 90:
    visibleSig.affineTransformParams(new byte[] {0, 1, -2, 0, 100, 0})
              .formaterRectangleParams(new byte[]{0, 0, 100, 100});

    float temp = yAxis;
    yAxis = visibleSig.getPageHeight() - xAxis - signImageWidth;
    xAxis = temp;

    temp = signImageHeight;
    signImageHeight = signImageWidth;
    signImageWidth = temp;

    break;
case 180:
    // Implement in a similar fashion
case 270:
    // Implement in a similar fashion
}

visibleSig.xAxis(xAxis)
          .yAxis(yAxis)
          .zoom(0)
          .signatureFieldName("Signature")
          .height(signImageHeight)
          .width(signImageWidth);
```

and the following method:

```
private int getPageRotation(String documentPath, int page) throws IOException
{
    try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(documentPath))
    {
        List<?> pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        PDPage pageObject =(PDPage) pages.get(page);
        return pageObject.getRotation();
    }
}
```

For **Rotate** values of 180 and 270, analogous corrections have to be made.

(Test methods `testLandscapeOriginal` and `testLandscapeFixed` in [SignLikeVanduc1102](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/sign/SignLikeVanduc1102.java))

Comment: thank you a lot,I think that code should be put in pdfbox source, event pdfbox2.0.0RC didn't support this feature.

Comment: *I think that code should be put in pdfbox source* - Well... no... I think the PDFBox code should be really fixed in this respect. The code above is merely a work-around... ;)

Comment: Sorry @mkl, I am so stupid, I can not find the document for parameters of  ```visibleSig.affineTransformParams(new byte[] {0, 1, -2, 0, 100, 0})
              .formaterRectangleParams(new byte[]{0, 0, 100, 100});``` . I want to finish *180* and *270* cases.

Comment: I can not rotate 180 with ```visibleSig.affineTransformParams(new byte[] {0, 1, -2, 0, 100, 0}) .formaterRectangleParams(new byte[]{0, 0, 100, 100});``` after change this params.... So for 180. I rotated the image 180 before put it in  visibleSign. For 270 case. I also rotated 180 and perform 90 rotate of @mkl

Comment: @mkl I've created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3671 . The 90° case needed a slightly different transform, which was not supported by PDFBox itself, due to it accepting only byte (!) transform matrix elements. This has been fixed in snapshot for 2.* and trunk only and the byte methods have been deprecated.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Ah, thanks for reminding me about this issue, I really should check whether sd dss has this issue, too...

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Und vielen Dank für die Blumen in dem Mailinglistenthread. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Starting with version 2.0.5, adjusting the signature field for rotated pages will be possible with the `adjustForRotation()` call. In the [CreateVisibleSignature.java example](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateVisibleSignature.java?view=markup), this line

```
visibleSignDesigner.xAxis(x).yAxis(y).zoom(zoomPercent);
```

has to be changed to this:

```
visibleSignDesigner.xAxis(x).yAxis(y).zoom(zoomPercent).adjustForRotation();
```

The change ([issue PDFBOX-3671](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3671)) is partially based on the answer by @mkl. It will not be available for 1.8.*.

**Update 24.10.2018:**

All 2.0.* versions up to 2.0.12 had the problem that `adjustForRotation()` was hard-coded for 200 x 100 image size. This has been fixed in 2.0.13. Alternatively derive your own `PDVisibleSignDesigner` and extend `adjustForRotation()` with the correct implementation:

```
public PDVisibleSignDesigner adjustForRotation()
{
    switch (rotation)
    {
        case 90:
            float temp = yAxis;
            yAxis = pageHeight - xAxis - imageWidth;
            xAxis = temp;

            affineTransform = new AffineTransform(
                    0, imageHeight / imageWidth, -imageWidth / imageHeight, 0, imageWidth, 0);

            temp = imageHeight;
            imageHeight = imageWidth;
            imageWidth = temp;
            break;

        case 180:
            float newX = pageWidth - xAxis - imageWidth;
            float newY = pageHeight - yAxis - imageHeight;
            xAxis = newX;
            yAxis = newY;

            affineTransform = new AffineTransform(-1, 0, 0, -1, imageWidth, imageHeight);
            break;

        case 270:
            temp = xAxis;
            xAxis = pageWidth - yAxis - imageHeight;
            yAxis = temp;

            affineTransform = new AffineTransform(
                    0, -imageHeight / imageWidth, imageWidth / imageHeight, 0, 0, imageHeight);

            temp = imageHeight;
            imageHeight = imageWidth;
            imageWidth = temp;
            break;

        case 0:
        default:
            break;
    }
    return this;
}
```